# Submitted character encoding -- _charset_ hidden field

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, windows-1252

For our web app, we have multiple HTML pages containing text areas.  All of our pages are rendered with an ISO-8859-1 charset.  When the page is accessed through IE6 on a Windows machine and special characters such as a "smart quote" are copied in to the text area, some of our pages submit the page using the Windows 1252 character encoding.  On the others, the pages appear to submit using the UTF-8 character encoding.  I've been tracking the submit character encoding by using the following hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_charset_" />
```

On the Windows 1252 submit character encoding pages, we receive a value of "windows-1252".

On the UTF-8 submit character encoding pages, we receive a blank value.

On the backend, we are using ISO-8859-1.  While ideally we would want the submit character encoding, I do not see an option for forcing that behavior on IE 6.  Given the choice between Windows 1252 and UTF-8, I would prefer the content be submitted in Windows 1252 so that is more likely to render correctly when the page re-renders in ISO-8859-1.

I've looked into our pages in some depth and nothing jumps out at me as the reason why some pages submit in one character encoding.

1) When IE 6 returns a *charset* of blank, does that in fact equate to UTF-8?  Does IE 6 always return a charset of blank when the submit character encoding is UTF-8, or only when it is unable to properly determine what character encoding to use?

2) What possible differences could there be on the pages that would result in IE 6 picking Windows 1252 on some pages and UTF-8 on others?  I scanned the page for UTF-8 characters and for any accept-charset attributes and could not find either.

Additional Note:  I found the information on the *charset* hidden input at the following link.

http://web.archive.org/web/20060427015200/ppewww.ph.gla.ac.uk/~flavell/charset/form-i18n.html

Comment: Do you have a "charset=..." attribute on your HTML form(s)?  If not, try adding one.

Comment: I tried providing an "accept-charset" on the form using "windows-1252" and "iso-8859-1".  This did not appear to make any difference in behavior.  This is possibly a result of "buggy" support of this attribute by IE (http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/form/accept-charset).

Answer (score 0):

MSDN states that IE only accepts "utf-8" as a value for this attribute.

Comment: Let's be clear here: the \_charset\_ form field is filled in by the client browser when it submits the form to the server. It's not something that the client specifies.

Answer (score 0):

The hidden field named `_charset_` has special treatement by [HTML5 conforming](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute) clients:

> [...]An ASCII case-insensitive match for the name *charset* is special: if
> used as the name of a Hidden control with no value attribute, then
> during submission the value attribute is automatically given a value
> consisting of the submission character encoding.

The submission character encoding is selected according to the [following algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#selecting-a-form-submission-encoding):

> If the user agent is to pick an encoding for a form, it
> must run the following steps:
>
> 1. Let encoding be the document's character encoding.
> 2. If the form element has an accept-charset attribute, set encoding to
>    the return value of running these substeps:
>
>    1. Let input be the value of the form element's accept-charset attribute.
>    2. Let candidate encoding labels be the result of splitting input on
>       ASCII whitespace.
>    3. Let candidate encodings be an empty list of character encodings.
>    4. For each token in candidate encoding labels in turn (in the order in
>       which they were found in input), get an encoding for the token and, if
>       this does not result in failure, append the encoding to candidate
>       encodings.
>    5. If candidate encodings is empty, return UTF-8.
>    6. Return the first encoding in candidate encodings.
> 3. Return the result of getting an output encoding from encoding.

So I think that if you do not receive a `_charset_` form parameter at backend, you should assume the character encoding is `UTF-8`